# Sum of the intensity values of all pixels in image segment

Tags: python, image, numpy, math, image-processing

According to the formula that is shown below, I need to calculate an average threshold value by dividing the sum of intensity values in segment on the number of pixels in segment.

[image: formula]

where Xi' is a binary mask (`structure_mask`), |Xi'| is a number of ones (`xi_modulus`).
I(x,y) is a pixel intensity.

```
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
...
...
structure_mask = np.logical_and(magnitude_mask, intensity_mask).astype(np.uint8)
xi_modulus = np.count_nonzero(structure_mask.all(axis=2))
intensity_sum  # = ??
```

How to calculate the sum of intensities with `numpy`?

**EDITED:** Based on the @HansHirse's answer I've tried to do the following:

```
thresh_val = np.mean(img_gray[structure_mask])
```

And I've got `IndexError: too many indices for array`

Where `structure_mask` was of shape `(1066, 1600,1)` and `img_gray` -
`(1066,1600)`

**UPDATED:** Just a dummy mistake. Shape mismatch was fixed by proper indexing

```
structure_mask = np.logical_and(magnitude_mask, intensity_mask)[:, :, 0]
```

Comment: Use `np.squeeze(structure_mask)` to get rid of the additional dimension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using NumPy's [boolean array indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing), you can easily access the desired values. You just need to pay attention, that your `mask` (or segment) is of NumPy's `bool_` type.

Let's see this short code snippet, where I compare the mean obtained from `np.mean` with the one explicitly calculated by the given formula:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Some artificial image
img = np.uint8(255 * np.tile(np.linspace(1, 0, 400), (400, 1)))
cv2.imshow('img', img)

# Some mask (or segment)
mask = np.zeros((400, 400), np.uint8)
mask[10:390, 10:30] = 255
cv2.imshow('mask', mask)

# Convert mask to bool_ type
mask = np.bool_(mask)

# Calculate mean by NumPy's mean
mean = np.mean(img[mask])
print('mean by np.mean:\n', mean)

# Calculate mean explicitly by given formula
mean = np.sum(img[mask]) / np.count_nonzero(mask)
print('mean by formula:\n', mean)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Outputs (images omitted here):

```
mean by np.mean:
 242.05
mean by formula:
 242.05
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I should accept Your answer but I've got an error because of shape mismatch. I've updated the question for You, please check It out

Comment: 1) Use `np.squeeze(structure_mask)` to get rid of the additional dimension. 2) I edited my answer and set up a `uint8` image - sorry for confusion.

Comment: Yep, I've already fixed this by slicing `structure_mask`, same effect as np.squeeze()

Answer (score 1):

numpy supports logical indexes so

```
magnitude_mask[intensity_mask].mean()
```

will give you what you want.

if you insist on having the sum use

```
magnitude_mask[intensity_mask].sum()
```